# how to insert values to a field from another fields

Tags: php, sql

i already input about a thousand values to a table but my client want a "little" revision that ihave to insert a field (fulldetail) is there a way to  get the values of the fields (acount, fname, mname, lname) and combind and put into the field (fulldetail).

Comment: Have you tried anything ? If you tried please share it...

Comment: i can only think that ihave to insert it 1by 1.  i tried sub query but it dosent work, also some q&a here and other site igot nothing

Comment: concatenate all columns and insert into one... It will be like yours...

Comment: .... _why_ do they want this revision?  For one thing, you could potentially just create a view (stored query), or even just concatenate the rows during any queries.  That field is unlikely to be queryable for anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the table structure (adding the new column), you can execute a mysql query like this:

```
UPDATE `table_users` 
SET `fulldetail` = CONCAT_WS( " ",`acount`,`fname`,`mname`,`lname` )
```

Comment: you're a diamon